# How to convert a wordpress site into a typo3 site?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, typo3

I already have a wordpress site i am trying to convert it into typo3. But i cannot find any help or tutorial regarding this pls someone help me?

Answer (score 4):

I am afraid, there is no easy converter or so for this. Typo3 is one of the more powerful, but also way more complicated cms out there.

The whole way Typo3 works is completely different.

So I am afraid you process will be creating the new Typo3 site in the image of the old site - then have a decent cut'n'paste orgy.

You might have a look in the Typo3 Extension Repository if there is any extension that offers to import a Wordpess XML export.

Edit: See if these help you in any way

http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/timtab_import_wp

http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/gl_wordpress

http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/ws_wordpressgrab

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some knowledge of TYPOscript, you might have to start your website from scratch or have a professional handle the conversion for you.

To avoid copy/pasting, you can try [this tutorial](http://vimeo.com/64951051), but it still won't work for design and extensions.